# Is there a way to use tqdm (progress bar) with ElasticSearch bulk upload?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, tqdm

As the heading states, I'm looking for a nice visual way to check my ES client upload

I can either use:

```py
for i in tqdm(<my_docs>):
    es_client.create(...)
```

but I want to use the recommended (by ES) way:

```py
helpers.bulk(...) <- how to add tqdm here?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but instead of using `bulk`, you need to use [`streaming_bulk`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.15.0/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk). Unlike `bulk`, which only returns the final result in the end, `streaming_bulk` yields results per action. With this, we can update `tqdm` after each action.

The code looks more or less like this:

```py
# Setup the client
client = Elasticsearch()

# Set total number of documents
number_of_docs = 100

progress = tqdm.tqdm(unit="docs", total=number_of_docs)
successes = 0

for ok, action in streaming_bulk(
    client=client, index="my-index", actions=<your_generator_here>
):
    progress.update(1)
    successes += ok

print(f"Indexed {successes}/{number_of_docs} documents")
```

Comment: Sometimes this does not update the progress bar. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: It works perfectly for me, maybe related to the update interval of tqdm? I also recommend using `_ = progress.update(1)`, this avoids endless "True" printing when running interactively